# Wasmer host functions accessing memory

Tags: rust, webassembly

I have a project where I used wasmer_runtime, and I tried to update it just to use Wasmer.

I struggle with memory access in host functions. Before, I had the following:

```
    fn hostFun(ctx:&mut wasmer_runtime::Ctx, ...) -> ... {
       ...
       let memory = ctx.memory(0);
       let data = memory.view()[index];
       ...
    }
```

However, in wasmer to my knowledge, the functions can only receive a custom environment and do not gain access to a context. Further, where I have to define the custom environment (the import section), the memory does not yet exist as the import section is needed to create the *Instance*, which provides the memory. What is the preferred way to access the memory from host functions in wasmer?

Comment: This used to be somewhat easier before 3.0, but the [migration docs](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/blob/v3.0.0/docs/migration_to_3.0.0.md#after) should have you covered. There doesn't seem to be a full-blown example of how to use `FunctionEnv` with `Memory`, but there's at least [one](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/blob/v3.0.0/examples/imports_function_env.rs) for `FunctionEnv`. If you piece together a nice example from the two, you could post it as an answer here and maybe even submit it as a PR?

Comment: I managed first to get the memory into the FunctionEnv, then realized that to access the memory, I need the Store as well, so I added the store to the env as well, but now I do no longer have the store as it moved to the env and I need to call functions inside the wasm. So I passed out the FunctionEnv as FunctionEnvMut. Sadly the Function FunctionEnvMut does not implement Send, so I got stuck again. If my application would have been single-threaded I would have succeeded.

Comment: Yup, I'm stuck too. The `Store` isn't clone, you require a mutable reference to it to call any wasm function, and you require a (non-mut) reference to it to access memory. I suppose you might want to ask this on the wasmer slack. (There's already [related](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/discussions/3675) questions on GH.)

Comment: I needed to do an ugly unsafe copy of a Store pointer, combined with a restructuring of my programme. It works in my case but I'm not sure if it works in generally, so I'm not conftable posting it as answer, especially as it is an ugly solution

Comment: Ooooh. I found something. https://docs.rs/wasmer/latest/wasmer/trait.AsStoreRef.html#impl-AsStoreRef-for-FunctionEnvMut%3C%27_%2C%20T%3E A `FunctionEnvMut` will basically work as a store, and you can use it to obtain a memory view. It's kinda documented in the migration guide, but I'm sure I would have missed, even if I'd read the whole thing. I was looking at how wasmer implements wasi. :)

Comment: Changing from the migration docs, I had to say `env_mut.memory = Some(instance.exports.get_memory("memory")?.clone());`, which matches the [commented wasi example](https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/blob/ef5dbd498722d1852ef05774f2c50f886c32ba80/examples/wasi_manual_setup.rs#LL52C5-L52C65). Yeah, and then I could `env.as_store_ref();` or whatever in the function to use along with the memory from env instance.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in the comments, you can do this by creating an environment containing the memory and passing this to the function.

```rust
struct Env {
    memory: Option<Memory>,
}

fn hostFn(mut env: FunctionEnvMut<Env>, ...) {
    let (env_data, store) = env.data_and_store_mut();
    let memory_view = env_data.memory.unwrap().view(&store);
    ...
}

let mut store = Store::default();
let env = FunctionEnv::new(&mut store, Env { memory: None });
let imports = imports! {
    "env" => {
        "hostFn" => Function::new_typed_with_env(&mut store, &env, hostFn),
    }
};

let instance = Instance::new(&mut store, &module, &import_fns).unwrap();
let memory = instance.exports.get_memory("memory").unwrap().clone();
env.as_mut(&mut store).memory = Some(memory);
```

Comment: @Markus_Knecht Does the submission above answer your question?

Comment: The proposed solution works fine with LLVM 17 and wasmer 4.2.6. Tested yesterday.